# Load balancing with docker swarm

Tags: docker, docker-compose, load-balancing, haproxy, docker-swarm

I have configured a 2 node docker swarm with a manager node `pi-manager` and a worker node `pi-worker` on a stack of 2 Raspberry Pi 3 Model 3 B running Raspbian. I have created an image that runs a helloworld type webpage on a local host that also identifies the container that the page is running on. Example:

[image: example of docker image webpage]

From the docker manager node I can create the service “flairhello” and then scale it to 2 continers (we will call them A and B) .

**Expected Behavior:**

The behavior I expected to get was that when I visited each localhost I would get the webpage displaying the container ID running on that host. For example if `pi-manager` has container `A` and `pi-worker` has container `B`. When I visit localhost address of `pi-manager` I would expect to see the container ID of `A` and when I visit the localhost address of `pi-worker` I would expect to see the container ID of `B`. This is NOT what is happening.

**Current Behavior:**

The behavior I am experiencing is that for some amount of time if I visit the localhost at either `pi-manager` or `pi-worker` I am directed to container `A`’s web page and then for the next section of time no matter which localhost (`pi-manager` or `pi-worker`) I visit I am always directed to Container `B`. I guess this is the built in load balancing of Docker swarm?

**Questions:**

How can I use a load balancer to get the behavior I want from my swarm?

What tools do I have to use? Docker compose? Haproxy image? (seen these mentioned from reading on this?

Are there any good tutorials for this process?

---

UPDATE:

Steps to create a Network Load Balancer with HAProxy in my answer below!

Answer (score 4):

Yes this is correct. The Docker swarm has swarm routing mesh https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/ingress/, and this is not sticky(ipvs) per design. If you like to be sticky, you have to deploy a loadbalancer in your stack which supports session stickiness, for example Traefik (https://traefik.io/).

But you can also go with Nginx, for example, like we do. -> https://github.com/n0r1sk/border-controller. But this is more sophisticated.

Comment: Im developing this project as a kind of example to display load balancing so that when I go to a main page the traffic is redirected to these two different containers running on `pi-manager` and `pi-worker`. So if you refresh a page the container address is different and you can illustrate the load balancing feature. Is this possible with Nginx or HaProxy? Thakk you for your example I see that it is a sticky connection How exactly is it working?

Comment: do you think I can convert this docker file to work on the ARM architecture?

Comment: If there is not a running web service on the container will i still be redirected to a node with the service running?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @kleinsasserm for pointing me in right direction I found a solution to my problem! I created a load balancer using a base HAProxy docker image and its Round Robin load balancing algorithm to create a hello world web page that will display the container it is on, alternating the container each refresh! This is a lab project used to demonstrate load balancing using docker.

Steps for this solution:

In order to set up and configure this Load balancer I did the following:

1. Created HAProxy Docker Image

   - Create a directory for your image

     ```
     $ mkdir haproxyImage
     $ cd hapoxyImage
     ```
   - Create you're docker file with the following contents

     ```
     FROM haproxy:1.7
     COPY haproxy.cfg /usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
     ```
   - Create your `haproxy.cfg` file

     ```
     global
         daemon                       
         log 127.0.0.1 local0 notice 
         maxconn 256                 


     defaults
         log     global
         mode    http
         option  httplog
         option  dontlognull
         retries 3
         option redispatch
         timeout connect  5000
         timeout client  10000
         timeout server  10000

     listen stats
         bind 0.0.0.0:80 # This is the page you will access
         mode http
         stats enable
         stats uri /haproxy?stats
         stats realm Strictly\ Private
         stats auth A_Username:user
         stats auth Another_User:password
         balance roundrobin # Defines our balancing algorithm as round robin.
         option httpclose
         option forwardfor
         server pi-manager <ip address>:8080 check # Docker node
         server pi-worker1 <ip address>:8080 check # Docker node
         # Add more docker nodes here
     ```
   - Build your Docker image

     ```
     $ docker build -t swarm-haproxy .
     ```
2. Start your Docker Swarm Service:

   ```
   $ docker service create -p 8080:80 --name helloworld --replicas 10 <image name>
   ```
3. Start you HAProxy image **I am running this on a computer not the pi stack**

   ```
   $ docker run -d -p 80:80 swarm-haproxy
   ```
4. On the Machine running the HAproxy image go to http://0.0.0.0 refresh the page to show the different containers running the same service

   ---

   References:

   - [HAProxy Configuration Manual](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.8/configuration.html#daemon)
   - [How To Use HAProxy to Set Up HTTP Load Balancing on an Ubuntu VPS](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-haproxy-to-set-up-http-load-balancing-on-an-ubuntu-vps#testing-load-balancing-and-failover)
   - [bhameyie/haproxy.cfg](https://gist.github.com/bhameyie/07c1ee9aaa3e8a200c8c)